# Multiple listeners to single promise

Tags: javascript

I have a module with an asynchronous function `init()` which is invoked multiple times. However, I only want the effect of the `init()` function to trigger once and any subsequent calls should just wait for that initial promise to resolve.

Here is my current code. The error in this example is that the second time the `init()` function is called, it is immediately resolved since the script tag already exists. I would like to wait for the `onload` callback from the script created on first `init()` invocation.

```js
let scriptExists = false;

// This function should only be called once
// Returns a mock script that calls onload after 1000ms
function addScript() {
  const mockScript = {
    onload: () => {}
  };
  setTimeout(() => mockScript.onload(), 1000);
  return mockScript;
}

// Add script and wait for it to load
function init() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (!scriptExists) {
      const script = addScript();
      scriptExists = true;
      script.onload = resolve;
    } else {
      // TODO: This should only resolve if the script has loaded
      resolve();
    }
  });
}

// Wait for the script to load, then add message
async function doSomethingNice() {
  await init();
  console.log("nocie");
}

// Wait for the script to load, then add message
async function doSomethingElse() {
  await init();
  console.log("something else");
}

doSomethingNice();
doSomethingElse();
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-cohen-9k4bf?file=/src/index.js

Comment: How about using a variable (property if used in class) to store the result and access that whenever necessary? `const initJob = init()`

Comment: Could you provide a complete  and working example ? (using JSFiddle for instance) Here your issue is not clear, and it could either be due to the fact you are missing a `resolve()` call in your promise, or you would need to `await`the `doSomethingNice` function, or even something else. Anyway, if the question would have a working example, it would be way easier to help you!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that seems to be pointing in the right direction. However, I only want to invoke `init()` when calling any of the other functions.

Comment: I've added working example now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set up your `init` function so that it only does the work once, and on subsequent calls it returns the promise from the first time:

```
let promise;
function init() {
  if (!promise) {
    promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.id = SCRIPT_ID;
      script.onload = resolve;
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = 'https://www.example.com/';
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    });
  }
  return promise;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this seems to work! I didn't think that the promise would resolve after already resolving once, like a callback.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example, I think if you use it in the context of a class it will be a better code pattern.

```
function init() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log("run");
    if (!document.getElementById("script")) {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.id = SCRIPT_ID;
      script.onload = resolve;
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = "https://www.example.com/";
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  });
}

var loader = undefined;

async function doSomethingNice() {
  !loader ? (loader = init()) : await loader;
  console.log("nice");
}

async function doSomethingElse() {
  !loader ? (loader = init()) : await loader;
  console.log("something else");
}

doSomethingNice();
doSomethingElse();
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically we do not have any Native API to check the state of the promise,
So what we can do is to have a variable and check them with another function that returns a Promise .

I was not able to completely use your sample code, but this is a working example, Given that a promise resolves, we move on to the other call.

```js
let PromiseState = false;
const promiseStateTimer = 1000;

// this function is responsible to manage the state
function checkState() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const checkInterval = setInterval(() => {
      // console.log(PromiseState);
      if (!PromiseState) {
        clearInterval(checkInterval);
        resolve(PromiseState);
      }
    }, promiseStateTimer);
  });
}


function init() {
  // change state ------------------- !
  if (!PromiseState) {
    PromiseState = !PromiseState;
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // revert back the state while resolving -------------------- !
      PromiseState = !PromiseState;
      resolve("Hello");
    }, 3000);
  });
}

async function doSomethingNice() {
  await checkState();
  await init();
  console.log("something nice");
}


async function doSomethingElse() {
  await checkState();
  await init();
  console.log("something else");
}

doSomethingNice();
doSomethingElse();
```

As per the promiseStateTimer, the state of the PromiseState is checked for every one second, and then the values are resolved, But you still need to add in some patch work to your listened Promise to make them work.